# Network manager does not show Mobile Broadband

Tags: networking

I have an internal Mobile Broadband network card on my laptop but the network manager does not pick it up. I only see WIred and Wireless.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently [an open issue](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-networking/issues/2) on GitHub about this and I have just recently got a Mobile Broadband device to do some development and testing so I can hopefully get this feature implemented.

However, in the mean time, you may still be able to configure your card by doing the following:

`Settings -> Network -> Edit Connections (at the bottom) -> Add -> Mobile Broadband`

If your device has been detected and has drivers, you should be able to configure it following those menus.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the procedure of adding broadband. The problem is that I am contiuously switching between Wireless and Mobile and need an easy way to select. Currently I have to have my mobile connection "Automatically connect to this network when available."

Comment: suggest you check out the mncli command (network manager CLI) you may be able to set it there and if so ... you should be able to script it which should solve your issue